# How can I fix the "undefined is not a function" error - React Native and Firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native

I am building a simple auth app from a template (https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/react-native-firebase-tutorial/). The original repo is: https://github.com/instamobile/react-native-firebase
The first line of the config file needs to be changed to import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";.

I have no idea why I am getting the following when I try to register an account:

> ERROR  TypeError: undefined is not a function, js engine: hermes

It could be an error somewhere in the Firebase call, but I have no idea what. The call is made in screens/RegistrationScreen/RegistrationScreen.js

I should be able to see a new user created in Firebase.

A new user is not created, and the app seems to crash at the point of making the Firebase call.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"